# Nodejs Restify Collection/Array param

Tags: node.js, rest, restify

I am in need to send multiple items over rest web service being developed over Nodejs + Restify. I can send single object e.g. User.

Suppose, my app got 10 - 100 users at once and want to upload on server via Restful web service developed in nodejs/restify. What would be good solution for this?

Comment: Can you show some code, where you are able to send single object User(as you said in question)? Even check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830448/how-to-parse-read-multiple-parameters-with-restify-framework-for-node-js) you may get some idea

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that through a jQuery Ajax Request. You can see my post for the solution.
[Post jQuery JSON Object to NodeJs Restify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922379/post-jquery-json-object-to-nodejs-restify)

Answer (score 0):

You can put you array in a Json, and then send it to your web service in one url parameter using JSON.stringify(your json)