# How to parse/read multiple parameters with restify framework for Node.JS

Tags: node.js, query-string, request.querystring, querystringparameter, restify

**Scenario**: We developer are trying to replace a web service (written in C#.Net) with Node.JS Restful API.

**Issue**: Now we need to handle the incoming request as is (we don't have control over it). So the following is the format of the incoming URL:

> http://www.website.com/Service.aspx?UID=Trans001&FacebookID=ae67ea324&GetDetailType=FULL

I am able to handle the URL like:

> http://www.website.com/service/Trans001/ae67ea324/FULL

I can parse/read the parameter from the above URL

Code:

```
var server = require('restify').createServer();
function respond(req, res, next) {
    console.log("req.params.UID:" + req.params.UID);
    console.log("req.params.FacebookID:" + req.params.FacebookID);
    console.log("req.params.GetDetailType" + req.params.GetDetailType);
}
server.get('/service/:UID/:FacebookID/:GetDetailType', respond);
server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

**Question**: How can I read the multiple parameters from the URL which is formatted like `http://www.website.com/Service.aspx?UID=Trans001&FacebookID=ae67ea324`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You just need to load the query parser plugin like so;

```
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());
```

Comment: True. This will enable reading query string params via req.query.my_param.

Answer (score 5):

**Restify 5 (2017) answer:**

As of restify 5 you can now setup the query parser like this:
`server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());`.

If you use this plugin you can access the parsed params in `req.query`.

For additional options and information, take a look into the restify documentation: http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#queryparser

Answer (score 2):

Simon's answer is no longer valid as restify's queryParser has been moved to the restify-plugins package. The updated solution is

```
server.use(require('restify-plugins').queryParser());
```

Comment: And now `restify-plugins` is deprecated... the updated solution is
`server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());`