# URL design in node.js routing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently trying to figure out how can I re-design an incoming url request in node.js and read the parameters from there.I am using restify.

In my router.js :

```
server.get('/myDomainName/myService/:location/:userId',myFunction);
```

I am getting the "location" and "userId" as parameter from here and further processing.

This is working perfectly. But I need to redesign the URL like ,

```
/myDomainName/myService?location={someLocation}&userId={someID}.
```

So, I have designed the URL like this :

```
/myDomainName/myService?location=:x&userId=:y
```

But when I am trying to read the value of x and y (`console.log(request.params.x)`) , they are **undefined**. I need to use that x and y value for further processing.

What I am doing wrong here for URL design ? How can I implement this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse/read multiple parameters with restify framework for Node.JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830448/how-to-parse-read-multiple-parameters-with-restify-framework-for-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can set the url like: 
`/myDomainName/myService`
and get the params from `req.query.location` and `req.query.userId`

This might help you: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Understood the difference between req.query and req.params . Unfortunately , still it is showing Undefined. Now What I am doing : server.get('/myDomainName/myService',myFunction); Then when I am hitting /myDomainName/myService?localtion=bd ,in browser. console.log(request.query.location); --> Undefined :(

Comment: You can print `req.query` and see what is the problem. It should work :/

Comment: You have set `server.use(restify.queryParser());` ?

Comment: Oh !!! That was the problem. No , I did not set that . Great Help . Now it's working. Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Query string is not included in the route path, its available in `req.query`. Just ignore query string when designing the route path.