# How to make request to static resource with parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify, staticresource

I have my node.js restify server, and folder with static resource

```
const restify = require('restify')

let server = restify.createServer()

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url)
});


server.get('/*', restify.plugins.serveStatic({
        directory: __dirname + '/static',
        default: 'index.html'
    }));
```

i'm trying to understand how to make get request to index.html with parameters like localhost:8080/index.html?token=123

and if token is valid, return index.html to client, else return error

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830448/how-to-parse-read-multiple-parameters-with-restify-framework-for-node-js

Answer (score 1):

You can chain multiple request handlers and the `next()` method - first do some parameters' validation and then, as a second handler, use the `serveStatic` method. Here's an example:

```
const restify = require('restify')

let server = restify.createServer()

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url)
});


server.get('/*', (request, response, next) => {
    const token = request.query.token;
    if(token !== '123') {
        //those two lines below will stop your chain and just return 400 HTTP code with some message in JSON
        response.send(400, {message: "Wrong token"});
        next(false); 
        return;
    }
    next(); //this will jump to the second handler and serve your static file
    return;
},
restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname + '/static',
    default: 'index.html'
}));
```